# what can the updateAppWidget function do?

Tags: android

In the Widget project ,I call the updateAppWidget function.Then the widget project is updated.
I want to kown how can the widget project is updated?
The onReseive() function is called?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you call updateAppWidget you are setting a widget ID and `RemoteViews`. `RemoteViews` is a content of your widget. You can inflate it from resources, set text to items, add on click listenters (not regular ones, but trough `PendingIntent`'s), etc...

Then `AppWidgetManager` draws/updates your widget using its ID and supplied `RemoteViews`

onReceive is called in another cases, i.e. then some broadcast intent is sent from a click on widget's button or any other event.